# Check if all items of an array are contained in a string

Tags: objective-c

For a feature I'm working on, I need to check if all items of an array are in a string.

I have something working right now

```
if (results.nbResult > 1) {
      NSString *terms = [results.queryTerms firstObject];
      int match = 0;
       NSArray *pathes = [terms componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
        for (Result *current in results.results) {
           for (NSString *path in pathes) {
              if ([current.destinationPath containsString:path]) {
                   match++;
                 }
                 if (match == pathes.count) {
                        item = current;
                    }
                }
                match = 0;
            }
        }
```

if my request terms are "54-01", my search engine give me two results (because the text is appearing twice in my search context).

In my first result, I have a reference to 54-01, but the destinationPath is "53 TITLE 01 SUBTITLE", and the second result have a reference to 54-01 too, but its destinationPath is "54 TITLE 01 SUBTITLE".

And I need to find the result which destinationPath contains all my request terms.

Nervertheless, I don't find that code really nice, and I was wondering if there's a better way to do it.

I was thinking about NSPredicate, but I don't see how to build that predicate.

If you have any idea about how to make this code nicer is welcome :)

Thank you.

Comment: can you show whats your array , whats your input and whats the  OP you expect.

Comment: It would be very helpful to add an example array and string and the expected result.

Comment: Terms array contains a query terms (which is a code like 54-01)

pathes will contains "54, 01"

And current.destinationPath contains a path like "53 Title 01 Subtitle", and "54 Title, 01 subtitle"

And I expect to check which one of the two results is the good one.

Comment: Please don't add information in the comments. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55020255/edit) your question. And please add an [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hope it helps, it's kind of tricky to explain it.

Comment: [`NSCompoundPredicate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscompoundpredicate) might fit your needs (several `AND` sub-predicates for example)

Comment: Another approach would be to construct a `Set` of string-components from your text and one for your terms, then you could just evaluate whether your terms is a subset of your components.